# Background Video Exceeds the Screen Size. Help Me Fix It

Tags: javascript, html, css

The background video exceeds the screen size, one has to scroll(Depending on the desktop size), in order to view the whole video at one place.

How do I edit the code in order to make it fill/fit the whole screen(without any scrolling needed)

Before anyone starts complaining about the fact that...this question has already been asked here, yes, it has been asked before(and I have referred to all those previous answers) but none of them helped me, thus asking again.

```css
.container video{
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <video src="https://cdn01.x-plarium.com/browser/content/landings/prelanding/backgrounds/001/step_01_low.mp4" autoplay="" loop="">
    </video>
    </div>
```

Comment: probably `max-width:100vw; max-height:100vh` ?

Comment: you also might wanna consider removing margins from the body, to get ride of the white space from the edges

Comment: @ZohirSalak, how to do that?

Comment: `body{margin:0;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the max-width to 100vw also the height to 100vh

```
.container video{
    max-width:100vw;
    max-height:100vh;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```css
.container video{
    max-width:100vw;
    max-height:100vh;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <video src="https://cdn01.x-plarium.com/browser/content/landings/prelanding/backgrounds/001/step_01_low.mp4" autoplay="" loop="">
    </video>
    </div>
```